# Why my session return null when I run on server but with postman it is working fine

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, session, session-state

**startup.cs**

```
        services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
        services.AddSession(options => {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(180);//You can set Time   
        });

        //Added for session state
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        });
```

**Dashboard controller:**

```
                //session data
                HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("VpsFundwiseBalanceList", vPSFundsDashboardDTO.FundWiseBalance);
```

**OtherController:**

```
 var CustomerTotalBalance = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<CustomerTotalBalance>("VpsFundwiseBalanceList");
```

It is absoultely working fine when I locally call dashboard controller api and then call other controller api, but when I deploy it on server it returns null

Comment: How do you test the API on local and server?

Comment: @Chetan When we test it with postman it is working fine but when we try to test with actual front end it fails

Comment: @Techgeeks1 I'm confused. This works fine locally but not if deployed? So postman + local works but postman + server does not?

Comment: What does it mean that the front-end test failed? It is normal for you to use postman after deploying to the server, but using the front-end url to test is null?

Answer (score 0):

### **You need to set cookies header for server call.**

> *Because you need to use cookies during your api call and Postman adds cookies to headers directly when it gets cookies from any call.*

---

- When you call an api that has operations with **session**, that api will return cookies as well.

[image]

- Postman creates cookies for next calls as below when it sees cookies on response as above.

> You can navigate that page by clicking Cookies button under Send button on Postman

[image]

- Now if you check another api call for localhost on Postman, you will see, it added cookies header automatically as below.

[image]